# Coordinate system of a MODIS file to be introduced in GDAL for transformation

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I am working on MODIS data using GDAL. When I extract coordinate system information of the files I got this:
`Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",
        DATUM["Not specified (based on custom spheroid)",
            SPHEROID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (2223901.039533000000000,0.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (926.625433139166600,-926.625433139166720)`

I have to transform the coordinate system of my other files into this coordinate system. But the problem is that I don't know how to introduce this coordinate system to my program.
I can't find *EPSG* or *Proj4* for it. Any solution or alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not recommend using the MODIS sinusoidal projection in analysis. It would be prudent to project your MODIS data to something a bit more tractable. You can request MODIS in a projected geographic (lat/long) coordinate system on the [MODIS Golbal Subsets](https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/MODIS/GLBVIZ_1_Glb/modis_subset_order_global_col5.pl) site .

That said I have used this as my CRS for MODIS "+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext"

Comment: thank you Jeffery. But I need to download the data from ftp website automatically using a Python program. I need the data stream for my spatial database. I don't think I could do it with the website you introduced. Another question is that if I choose to reproject the data to a well-known coordinate system, does it have significant resampling errors? or I can ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the supported coordinate reference system (CRS) used by many GIS applications both on the the desktop environment (ArcGIS, QGIS, Python, GDAL command line, GRASS etc. ) and web, from [Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org/). A quick [search](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=MODIS%20Sinusoidal%20) for MODIS Sinusoidal from the website, will show you all the supported CRS example as shown below:

- Well Known Text as HTML
- Human-Readable OGC WKT
- [Proj4](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6842/proj4/)
- OGC WKT
- JSON
- GML
- [ESRI WKT](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6842/esriwkt/)
- .PRJ File
- USGS
- MapServer Mapfile | Python
- Mapnik XML | Python
- GeoServer
- PostGIS spatial_ref_sys INSERT statement
- Proj4js format

You can simply copy the text or import files provided on the website to your favourite GIS software application.