# Coordinate system of a raster file to be introduced for transformation

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I am working on raster data using GDAL. When I extract coordinate system information of the files I got this: 
`PROJCS["Geostationary_Satellite",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Unknown datum based upon the custom ellipsoid",
        DATUM["D_Not specified (based on custom ellipsoid)",
            SPHEROID["Custom_ellipsoid",6378140,298.252981]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Geostationary_Satellite"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["satellite_height",35785831],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]`

I have to transform the coordinate system of my other files into this coordinate system. But the problem is that I don't know how to introduce this coordinate system to my program. I can't find EPSG or Proj4 for it. Any solution or alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coordinate system of a MODIS file to be introduced in GDAL for transformation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39116/coordinate-system-of-a-modis-file-to-be-introduced-in-gdal-for-transformation)

Answer (score 3):

How about using gdalwarp?

First copy the above well known text to 'target_srs.prf' (or whatever name you like).  Then:

```
    gdalwarp -t_srs target_srs.prf inputraster outputraster
```

Full documentation on gdalwarp [is here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).  I think that you can safely omit the s_srs flag as gdal should read the inputraster to get the srs.

Alternatively, what is your program?  QGIS?

Comment: The problem is gdalwarp sometimes (when the srs is so alien!)  can't recognize the source srs then it'll be a problem @Aragon .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way which I have used before([gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html)):

```
gdalbuildvrt myVRT.vrt *_sk.tif
```

Then open your myVRT.vrt file with any text editor and add your projection into .. as your .vrt file....

I hope it helps you...